# Auto newline in css selector with prettier

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, prettier

When I Use any CSS selector and use prettier in vscode to format......
It automatically puts each selector (separated by comma) into next line which is not then not detected by CSS...

*What I wrote :*

```
td,th,table {
  border: 5px solid greenyellow;
}
```

*After formatting (through prettier) :*

```
td,
th,
table {
  border: 5px solid greenyellow;
}
```

*My Prettier settings in vscode:*

```
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "auto",
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "useTabs": false,
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
  "filepath": "c:\\Users\\coder\\Desktop\\a.css",
  "parser": "css"
}
```

**Please Help !!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to fix this in the config file, it's a feature built into Prettier.

You need to add `/* prettier-ignore */` to the top of your CSS selector block to stop prettier from formatting that section of selectors.

Here's an example with it applied to the first section of the meyer-reset.

```css
/* prettier-ignore */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Oh Okay, Thanks !, But Prettier should fix this.........